# OpenAPI Swagger Code Gen C# Server Stub Throws Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have used the following command to generate the C# server stub code from a Swagger Yaml file:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli.jar generate \
  -i api.yaml \
  -g aspnetcore \
  -o ../
```

And it builds with no problem. However, when I tried to `dotnet run` it has reported the exception:

[image]

Detailed exception trace:

```
System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=The header contains invalid values at index 0: 'application.json'
  Source=Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser`1.ParseValue(StringSegment value, Int32& index)
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(StringSegment input)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ConsumesAttribute..ctor(String contentType, String[] otherContentTypes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, RuntimeType type, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.CreateActionModel(TypeInfo typeInfo, MethodInfo methodInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ApplicationModelFactory.CreateApplicationModel(IEnumerable`1 controllerTypes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.GetChangeToken()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Org.OpenAPITools.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_2(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in C:\Users\zhihualai\cloudservices\src\Org.OpenAPITools\Startup.cs:line 141
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at Org.OpenAPITools.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\zhihualai\cloudservices\src\Org.OpenAPITools\Startup.cs:line 139
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.HostingStartup.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.HostingStartup.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo somewhere in the code.
Can you do a "find all" (*usually CTRL + SHIFT + F*) and look for `application.json` and change it to `application/json` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the hint... the problem is the typo in Swagger Yaml file..